# SQL query to find a reporting officer to a employee

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, report

I want to know which employee is reporting to which employee in the organization
There are two tables.
Tables : **employee** and **reporting_hierarchy**

employee table:

```
employee_id
fullname
```

reporting_hierarchy table :

```
employee_id                 
officer_id
```

employee_id and officer_id is same As one employee is mapped to another employee as a reporting officer.

expecting Output like this

```
fullname(Employee) | fullname(Reproting officer)
ABC                |  XYZ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple query. Just join `employee` table twice with different aliases like:

```
SELECT
    e.fullname Employee,
    o.fullname ReprotingOfficer
FROM reporting_hierarchy
JOIN employee e on e.employee_id = reporting_hierarchy.employee_id
JOIN employee o on o.employee_id = reporting_hierarchy.officer_id;
```